# D3 Fill in area of linear chart by condition

Tags: d3.js

I have a dataset

```
[
  {
    date: '2015-12',
    value: 100,
    priority: null,

  },
  {
    date: '2016-01',
    value: 200,
    priority: 'high',
  },
  {
    date: '2016-02',
    value: 200,
    priority: null,
  },
  {
    date: '2016-03',
    value: 200,
    priority: null,
  },
  {
    date: '2016-04',
    value: 100,
    priority: 'low',
  },
  {
    date: '2016-05',
    value: 250,
    priority: 'low',
  },
  {
    date: '2016-06',
    value: 250,
    priority: null,
  },
  {
    date: '2016-07',
    value: 100,
    priority: null,
  },
  {
    date: '2016-08',
    value: 250,
    priority: null,
  }
]
```

I've create linear chart with D3 v4. Now I have to fill in chart's segments with background color from top to bottom by `priority` field value? like on image (High priority segment should fill in with red color, low - with green, etc.)
Could someone give an example how to implement this behavior, or advice the direction for researching?

Thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: If you want to fill the area underneath the line segments D3 has area() for this. var ```const area = d3.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(chartHeight)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value); });``` that can be used as a value for `d` attribute of a `path` tag

Comment: Hey, Cornel, thanks for you response, but I need to fill chart on the whole height, like I showed on the pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a band scale that will be used to calculate the width of every tick between two dates as such:

```
const bandScale = d3.scaleBand()
 .domain(data.map(item => item.date).slice(1))
 .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
 .paddingInner(0)
```

After that you can add a new iterator using a rect element before adding the path using:

```
svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('fill', d => d.priority !== null ? 
                        d.priority === 'high' ? '#FFBBB7' : '#CCFFC4' :
                        'transparent')
    .attr('x', d => x(new Date(d.date)))
    .attr('y', margin.top)
    .attr('width', bandScale.bandwidth())
    .attr('height', height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
```

Where you will add a rectangle for tick on the x axis where the fill depends on the priority.

Please see the following observable: https://observablehq.com/@cstefanache/simple-line-chart

Comment: Thank you very much, Cornel, I'll try this approach